# How can i view shell optin?

Tags: shell, fedora

I want to use `set -`  in fedora21. When i am writing this command in terminal but no happens( do not show the list of shell option), but i want to view the list of shell option. 
I want to use the commands `set-o` vi and `set +o` vi and like this. To use this command in fedora21 what should i do?

Comment: Clarify, please. What exactly do you expect to happen, and what is happening instead?

Comment: You might want to read the [The Set Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin) section of the bash manual.

Comment: if your current shell is a `dash` built with the *`SMALL`* build-time option `set -o vi` will have no effect because the bsd line editing library *`libedit`* was not linked in when it was compiled. that is the default compilation method for the default `dash` included on debians, anyway. im not sure if the same thing is true of fedora.

Comment: `set -` is not a command; `set` is. The dash is part of the option.

Comment: I want to display the list that show for example vi is off or on , Login_shell is off or on . display the list in fedora by " shopt"' command but in Cent Os by "set -" is. Now for set off or on for vi or like this what should i do?

Comment: @fzm: Check `$0` and `$SHELLOPTS` variables.

Comment: I am checking "$0" and it shows "bash" in terminal. I am writing  "echo $SHELLOPTS" in terminal it shows "braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor"

Answer (score 0):

This works fine with bash in any version of fedora I know of (just double-checked 22).  The only logical explanation is that you are not actually running bash.  Try the following two things:

- Explicitly run bash, then within bash try `set -o`.
- Run `echo $BASH_VERSION`.  If there's no such variable, you aren't using bash.

Comment: I am running echo $BASH_VERSION and show 4.3.30(1)-release.So there is the variable in bash.

Comment: Maybe include a terminal transcript of what you are doing.  For example, if I run `/bin/bash` followed by something visible like `set -o verbose`, it definitely works.

Comment: I want to display the list that show for example vi is off or on , Login_shell is off or on . display the list in fedora by " shopt"' command but in Cent Os by "set -" is. Now for set off or on for vi or like this what should i do?

Comment: I run /bin/bash it show binary file

Comment: I want to display the list that show for example vi is off or on , Login_shell is off or on . display the list in fedora by " shopt"' command but in Cent Os by "set -" is. Now for set off or on for vi or like this what should i do?i want to see the list that include  be vi

Comment: @fzm: Sorry, I'm confused by your comments.  When you say "I run /bin/bash it show binary file," do you mean you are unable to run /bin/bash?  That could be your problem.  Are you saying "shopt" is not working?  Also, if you just run "set -", all it does is clear "$@" not print anything.  Again, if you edit your question to show a transcript of what you believe is incorrect behavior after running /bin/bash, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: My meaning of run it is i am writing " vi bin/bash" in terminal to view contact this file.What are your mean of run? "shopt" command is working and displaying that list but "vi" is not in it. Now i want to by "set -" display the list , do this is not in fedora? Thank your kindness